# Automaticall replacing single catch clauses with duplicate catch clauses

Tags: java, catch-block, multi-catch

Does anyone know whether there is a tool or something similar to replace single catch clauses with duplicate code within it in java with multiple catch clauses to remove duplicate code?

Context is an upgrade vom java jdk6 to 7.

Thanks and cheers, 
Ste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a automatic way, You can do something like following

```
    try {
       // code
    } catch (Exception1 e1) {
      // caught Exception1
    } catch (Exception2 e2) {
      // caught Exception2
    }
```

You can change this to

```
    try {
       // code
    } catch (Exception1|Exception2 e) {
      // caught Exception1 or Exception2
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the idea, but does not anyone know a tool that can automate that?

Comment: @user3909296 if you are using `IDE` like `IntelliJIDEA` it will ask you to Collapse 'catch' blocks.